# Retry a HystrixCommand

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, hystrix

I've noticed that retrying a failed `HystrixCommand` just replays emitted error. Under certain circumstances, I'd like to replay it. One instance would be where a request is throttled by a downstream service; I'd like to wait and try again.

One way I can see is to use `Observable.defer`, but I'm sure there's a better way.

```
final AtomicInteger tries = new AtomicInteger(0);
final AtomicInteger retries = new AtomicInteger(0);

final Observable<Integer> command = Observable.defer(() -> new HystrixCommand<Integer>(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("test")) {
            @Override
            protected Integer run() throws Exception {
                final int i = tries.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.print("Try: " + i);
                if (i < 5) {
                    throw new ProvisionedThroughputExceededException("exceeded");
                }
                return i;
            }
        }.observe()
)
        .retry((attempts, error) -> {
            final Class<? extends Throwable> rootClass = Throwables.getRootCause(error).getClass();
            if (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException.class.isAssignableFrom(rootClass)) {
                final int i = retries.incrementAndGet();
                return i < 5;
            }
            return false;
        });

final int attempts = command.toBlocking().single();
assertEquals(5, attempts);
assertEquals(4, retries.get());
```